# viewDidLoad getting called every time

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a mainView(firstview) where clicking a button takes me to another view(second view) which contains tableview..where I'm parsing data from my server in viewDidLoad .the problem is if I close my second view using dismissmodalView and click the same button in my mainview.the controller goes to the viewDidLoad instead of viewDidAppear..this makes to load the server once again and populate the table view.

```
-(void)loadFeeds
{
    //Activity Indicator MBProgressHUD
    if(activity == nil){
        activity = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview:activity];
        [activity hide:YES];
    }

    //Pull to Refresh (Ego refresh header view) Declarations Facebook and Twitter
    if (_refreshHeaderViewTwitter == nil) {
        EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tblTwitter.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tblTwitter.bounds.size.height)];
        view.delegate = self;
        [self.tblTwitter addSubview:view];
        _refreshHeaderViewTwitter = view;
        [_refreshHeaderViewTwitter refreshLastUpdatedDate];
    }

    [activity show:YES];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        getTwitterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[Util getJsonArray:Twitter]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
                       ^{            
                           [self.tblTwitter reloadData];
                           [activity hide:YES];
                       });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the view controller to hang around until you dismiss its presenting view controller, then you could retain the view controller as a property

`@property (nonatomic, retain) MyModalViewController *myModalViewController;`

and lazy load it in it's getter method..

```
- (MyModalViewController *)myModalViewController
{
  if (_myModalViewController == nil)
  {
    _myModalViewController = [[MyModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  }
  return _myModalViewController;
}
```

then your view controller will hang around and if/when you get a memory warning, set the property to nil and it will unload correctly.

Answer (score 1):

dismissing the viewcontroller gets rid of it.

You are going to have to manage the persistance manually.

So you are going to need to save the last state of the view controller in some level of persistance higher than the viewcontroller. Wether thats to disk or perhaps even in the appdelegate. It's up to you, but the viewcontroller is working properly.

Comment: i ve got another table view where i m loading my feeds from youtube and parsing that in viewDidload when i close and open controller does nt getting into viewDidLoad but rather viewDidAppear

Comment: Are you saying when it opens again it is not reparsing?

Comment: yup.coz normally the controller comes to viewDidAppear and there will be previously cached data in array which will be tableview.but my problem is its coming to viewdidload every time i present and dismiss my modal view controller.which leads to reloading of tableview every single time

Comment: You aren't going to be able to prevent it. viewDidLoad is being called because the views were previously destroyed.